# AG-Grid: On Filter Menu Dismiss

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Looking to track when the Column Menu > Filter Menu popup is dismissed... can't find any info in Grid Events, Context Menu, or Filters that do it.

Basically looking for something like

```
toolPanelVisibleChanged
```

I need on dismiss to reset the filters to what is currently applied.

So, what I am trying to do and I have in place (everything minus the on dismiss) is:

1. Get filters currently applied, if any and house in a variable
2. If user clicks the filter menu and changes the filter, but cancels or clicks bg (which dismisses the menu) re-apply the filters in the variable on menu dismiss.

What happens is when the user makes a filter change, without applying it and they close the menu... and reopen it, they think that the filters shown checked are applied, but they are not bc applied was not clicked.

Helpful links that I've looked at:

```
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering
```

Using Angular 7, typescript, and ag-grid enterprise.